# How to have "simple" replacable placeholder text in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I want "simple" placeholder text (i.e. placeholder text that's replaced when the user starts typing).

I am trying the following code:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="hasVisibleChild(item) && item.display == 'Email'">
        <mat-icon fontIcon="mail" matPrefix></mat-icon>
        <mat-label matPrefix class="placeholder-text">Enter Email ID</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="email" (change)="onChange($event)" #emailAddress/>
    </mat-form-field>
```

However, the input appears before the text that I type:

[image]

Also, I tried the following:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="hasVisibleChild(item) && item.display == 'Email'">
        <input matInput type="email" (change)="onChange($event)" #emailAddress placeholder="Enter Email ID" />
    </mat-form-field>
```

However, the text appeared above the input:

[image]

Using the `<mat-placeholder>` tag had a similar effect to the second screenshot.

Does anyone know how I could change this to act like a "standard" placeholder text? Or am I better off bypassing Angular entirely and just using a standard HTML element?

Comment: Just use placeholder on the input, with a mat-label as well. Or, if you prefer no label, adjust the 'float'-settings for mat-form-field and omit the mat-label.

Comment: @LarsRødal Unfortunately, using the `placeholder` attribute on the input results in the second screenshot, which isn't what I was trying to achieve. Is there some other way I should be setting the placeholder?

Comment: Added an answer instead, slightly different from my comment (I didn't remember 100% correct :p )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no label is wanted (only placeholder), you can do it like this:

```
  <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'" appearance="fill">
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
  </mat-form-field>
```

This shows placeholder when no value inserted, and only value when value present.

If you would like a label in addition to placeholder, you can do it like this:

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'always'" appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Fill form field</mat-label>
   <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
</mat-form-field>
```

The important settings here is the floatLabel, described here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#floating-label :)

The input styling can also be changed if you prefer another styles: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants

Comment: Note, instead of `[floatLabel]="'always'"` you can simplify to `floatLabel="always"`